# Android: Google maps API GeoPoint vs. android's Location, why microdegrees

Tags: android, google-maps

I'am working with android and the google maps API.

The Location-class in the android framework uses degrees while the maps GeoPoint-class uses microdegrees.

My question: Why is that the case? I have to make a presentation and it would be nice to have a reason for it.

GeoPoint description: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html
Location description: (cant post it cause of spam prevention, sorry)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably a speed optimization (working with integers is faster than working with floats).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but maybe someone coming here (like me a couple of weeks ago) will find that useful.

I've been really searching for an answer to the same question for some time now, just out of curiosity. I've found this question first, but the answer didn't really satisfied me. Today I accidentally stumbled upon this question: [Why are latitude and longitude values converted to 1E6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11317483/1820695)

The answer by CommonsWare coincides with what I've read and heard from various sources. Also the same answer applies to the question on why does OpenGL ES have `GL_FIXED` type :)